# Remove an event listener from a draggable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I am working with ES6 components in React and making a simple slider component.  On my `mousedown` event, I am adding a listener for `mousemove` as a handler for `onDrag` isn't quite responsive enough. I am trying to remove the `mousemove` listener on `mouseup` as that means the user is done dragging on the slider. However, I can't get my event listener off, and it keeps firing the `onDrag` function (will log "I still execute"). Am I missing something obvious? I tried passing a named function like other answers suggested, but it still fires.

ES6 code:

```
import React from 'react';

class PriceSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {positionX: 0, offset: null, dragging: null}
  }
  _onDrag(e) {
    console.log("i still execute")
    if(e.clientX > 0) {
      this.setState({positionX: e.clientX});
    }
  }
  _removeDragHandlers() {
    let node = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.circle1);
    node.removeEventListener("mousemove", this._onDrag.bind(this), false);
    return;
  }
  _addDragHandlers() {
    let node = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.circle1);
    node.addEventListener("mousemove", this._onDrag.bind(this), false);
    return;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({offset: this.refs.circle1.getDOMNode().getBoundingClientRect().left })
  }
  _onMouseDown(e) {
    this._addDragHandlers();
  }
  _onMouseUp(e){
    this._removeDragHandlers();
  }
  render() {
    let circle1Style = {left: this.state.positionX - this.state.offset}

    if(this.state.positionX === 0) {
      circle1Style = {left: this.state.positionX}
    }

    return(
      <div className="slider">
        <span className="value">Low</span>
        <span className="circle" style={circle1Style} onMouseDown={this._onMouseDown.bind(this)} onMouseUp={this._onMouseUp.bind(this)} ref="circle1"></span>
        <span className="line"></span>
        <span className="circle" ref="circle2"></span>
        <span className="value">High</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

With a named function, I tried doing something like:

```
node.addEventListener("mousemove", function onDrag() {
  if(!this.state.dragging)  {
    node.removeEventListener("mousemove", onDrag, false)
  }
})
```

To no avail.  Any help or suggestions on improving this are much appreciated. I do not have jQuery or other Javascript libraries included, and need to solve this without the help of a plugin or library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this._onDrag.bind(this)` returns a new function every time - so you add and then try to remove different functions. You need to do it once and then refer to the same function every time:

```
constructor(props, context) {
    …
    this._onDrag = this._onDrag.bind(this);
}
_removeDragHandlers() {
    …
    node.removeEventListener("mousemove", this._onDrag);
}
_addDragHandlers() {
    …
    node.addEventListener("mousemove", this._onDrag, false);
}
```

Comment: Ah, perfect-that's why I got the same result when I used a name function. I will go read the docs for `bind` once again. Thanks for answering!